# Correct way to see domain of function using DownValues?

Tags: hold, downvalues

Here's a simple function `g` defined for the natural numbers 1 through 10:

`Table[g[i] = i^2,  {i, 1, 10}]`

I now want to find the domain of g, namely the natural numbers 1 through 10. However:

```
In[228]:= dv = DownValues[g]

Out[228]=
{HoldPattern[g[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[g[2]] :> 4, 
 HoldPattern[g[3]] :> 9, HoldPattern[g[4]] :> 16, HoldPattern[g[5]] :> 25, 
 HoldPattern[g[6]] :> 36, HoldPattern[g[7]] :> 49, HoldPattern[g[8]] :> 64, 
 HoldPattern[g[9]] :> 81, HoldPattern[g[10]] :> 100}

In[231]:= dv[[4]]                                                               

Out[231]= HoldPattern[g[4]] :> 16

In[232]:= dv[[4,1]]                                                             

Out[232]= HoldPattern[g[4]]
```

The problem: nothing I do to `dv[[4,1]]` will give me back 4. ReleaseHold releases the hold and gives me 16 as expected. I found a workaround:

```
In[244]:= (dv[[4,1]] /. g -> Null)[[1,1]]                                       

Out[244]= 4
```

but this seems bad (even if I replace Null w/ a temporary variable or whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dom = Cases[DownValues[g], g[x_] :> x, Infinity]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

If you have definitions with multiple arguments, e.g. `g[-1, -2] = Pi`, you can do

```
dom = Cases[DownValues[g], g[x__] :> {x}, Infinity]
(* {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {-1, -2}} *)
```

The range is then very simply

```
ran = g @@@ dom
(* {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, π} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#[[1, 1, 1]] & /@ DownValues[g]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

Comment: alternative: `ReleaseHold[First /@ DownValues[g] /. g -> Identity]`.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I always thought `dv[[4,1,1,1]]` was the same thing as `dv[[4,1,1]][[1]]` but apparently not, since `dv[[4,1,1]]` is just the numeric value 16. Does this magic work only because of the Hold value? I'm guessing when I type `dv[[4,1,1]]` it gets evaluated to 16, but it's "raw form" is somehow different. Ah, got it `dv // FullForm` shows what this really is.